# Pine Script not picking ATR Value

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

In the below code, no matter what ATR value (Period or factor) I input either in the inputs popup window or in code itself, results (bars or plotted line) are not changing even by 0.1 decimal value.  There is some sensitivity for ATR in this code hence values or result needs to change with change in ATR inputs. For other three, values change.

```
indicator("Wave", overlay=true)
Highest = input(high, title="Higher")
Lowest = input(close, title="Lower")
Lookback = input(5, title="Lookback")
ATRPeriod = input(25, title='Lenght ATR')
ATRFactor = input.float(9.5,title = "ATR Factor", minval = 0.5, step = 0.5)

A=ta.highest(Highest,Lookback)
B=ta.lowest(Lowest,Lookback)
C=ta.atr(ATRPeriod)*ATRFactor

D=A-C
E=B+C

barcolor(close>=((D+E)/2)?color.white:color.yellow)

plot(((D+E)/2), color=color.white)
```

Answer (score 0):

<sup>Converting OP-confirmed solution from a comment to an answer:</sup>

> D+E = (A-C)+(B+C) = A+B your plot does not depend on parameters C
> – [AnyDozer](https://stackoverflow.com/users/14860394/anydozer)   [Jan 7 at 20:08](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77773052/pine-script-not-picking-atr-value#comment137113953_77773052)